# Automatic change language in input texts PB 12.6

Tags: powerbuilder, input-language

I think the problem (if a problem) remains in Powerbuilder 12.6 in a migrated project. 
Each input text remembers the language that had been typed before I change the language in another input text.

Is there any way to fix this issue? E.g., change the language globally for every input text?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:
From PB12.6 help:

> In a DataWindow object, the input language in effect the first time a column gets focus becomes the default input language for that column. If you subsequently change the input language when that column has focus, the new input language becomes the default for that column. This behavior does not apply to columns that have the RightToLeft property set.

I suppose the only solution is the workaround using Windows API.

see: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3414562